# How can I select from Solr only where a MultiValueField is not empty?

Tags: search, solr

I'd like to get a collection of results from Solr whose multi-value fields are not empty. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: fieldName:* does not work for multivalued fields. field:[* TO *] works for me.

Answer (score 6):

As explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), you can use `field:[* TO *]` to match all documents where `field` is not empty.